# WordPress Admin Flattr API Include

Tags: wordpress, ssl, flattr

I have a WP website with SSL on the backend and I have been informed by my client that he gets an unsecure message when accessing this.. Have checked the NET panel in firebug and have traced it down to a nonsecure link reference to the Flattr API.

Please see attached image.

Does anyone know how to change this? Or why its even there? I just need to change it to https

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change `http` to `https` and the flattr script will be loaded over https instead and browsers will not throw a insecure content error.

You can also try our WordPress plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flattr/

Comment: I am not using any Flattr plugin.